# Error 404 wordpress redirecting URL

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, 404-error, site-url

i'm having problems after trying to redirect my website with wordpress. I wanted not to have something like that: "www.example.com/wordpress/".

So I did that in the wp-config file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http:// example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http:// example.com');
```

And now all I see is a 404 not found with my css and stuff but everything else is gone including the wp-admin part.

I'm lost and really need help !

I also tried editing my .htaccess file but even if the url has the same look as the right one, it's still a 404.

Here's the address http://zeekray.com/wordpress/

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Of note, if it did redirect to the root, which it isn't, there isn't a WordPress install there or the files to make one work. It's an incomplete subdirectory install

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be redirected to "http://www.zeekray.com/en/" .

But you don't have a folder like "/en", as far as I can see here http://www.zeekray.com , where the folders are shown.

Comment: This may help explain the issue but it doesn't solve the issue, can you explain how this answers the question rather than being better put as a comment?

Comment: My website is now working at this address: http://www.zeekray.com/wordpress/fr/. I forced the url directly into the database again and it worked this time.

Comment: So what would be the best way to change the URL? Can i just move all the "wordpress" folder content to the root of the "www" folder?

Comment: @TomJNowell I didn't manage to make a "comment", I wasn't allowed to since I am a beginner in the forum.
It said "You must have 50 reputation to comment." Apparantly I can comment on answers, but not on questions. Sorry, just trying to help.